# Helper Method for Generating Stubbed ICommand in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This helper method is designed to make stubbing `ICommand`s simpler.

Do you see any problems with this implementation?

```
public static ICommand GenerateCommandStub(
    Action<object> executeAction = null, 
    Func<object, bool> canExecuteFunc = null)
{
    var commandStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICommand>();
    commandStub.Stub(command => command.Execute(Arg<object>.Is.Anything))
        .Do(executeAction ?? (_ => { }));
    commandStub.Stub(command => command.CanExecute(Arg<object>.Is.Anything))
        .Do(canExecuteFunc ?? (_ => true));
    return commandStub;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine to me, although I would personally prefer to have method chaining rather than optional parameters just for semantic purposes. Are your arguments meant to be weakly typed (using `object`)? If I could, I would change that to something strongly typed, but that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: This looks like [`ICommand` from WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand), which is weakly typed.

Comment: Ah yes. I've never used WPF, so I didn't know

Comment: The `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods `ICommand` interface both accept an `object` instance, so I think that's what should be used here.  Nice idea with the method chaining.  It adds some complexity, but it makes it nicer for the consuming code.

Comment: Psst - it's method *overloading* ;)

Comment: Actually, I meant currying + overloading ;) Ie, `f(x) -> g(x, y)`